# What is $\lim_{q_1\to\infty}\frac{q_2^2}{ln(q_2^2)-1}\prod_{p=5}^{q_1}\frac{p-2}{p-1}$?

Tags: prime-numbers, infinite-product

q2 is the prime following q1. First part goes to infinity and second part to zero of course. I expect the product to go to infinity, but like to find the proof.

What is $$\lim_{q_1\to\infty}\frac{q_2^2}{ln(q_2^2)-1}\prod_{p=5}^{q_1}\frac{p-2}{p-1}$$

Comment: Did you mean to write $$\;\lim_{q_1\to\infty}\frac{q_2^2}{\log q_2^2-1}\prod_{p=5}^{q_1}\frac{p-2}{p-1}\;\;?$$

Comment: Your $q_2^2$ should not be there, see Mertens theorem giving the asymptotic of $\prod_{p\le x} (1-p^{-1})$, with $q_2^2$ it $\to \infty$.

Comment: Yes DonAntonio, that is the one. I am struggling with notation

Comment: Thanks @reuns to put me on the right track. I will study Mertens theorem to get the proof I need.

Comment: @reuns $q_2^2$ is there in my situation. Busy proving Goldbach......